# How to export one cell of a jupyter notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I'm currently working/prototyping into a *Jupyter* notebook. I want to run some of my code on a standalone *iPython* shell.

For now, I export my *iPython* code (file --> download as) and then execute it in my *iPython* (with %run). It works, but I would like to export only one cell or set of cells. So, that I can run only what I modified in my *Jupyter* notebook.

Comment: I am not sure whether it would make sense as in jupyter notebook, kernel  maintains the state of previously run commands which might not be the case with ipython %run command.

Comment: For a single cell you could simply copy and paste or use IPython magics: 1) %%writefile, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034373/how-to-load-edit-run-save-text-files-py-into-an-ipython-notebook-cell or 2) %save, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810/how-to-save-a-python-interactive-session command.

Comment: @RohanSadale what I want is to work both in my jupyter notebook and in my ipython shell. my notebook is made to be shared and when I want to make the command previously run on my notebook but with a bigger dataset and test some stuff on it, I made it on my ipython shell.

Comment: @Valentas your comment should be rewritten as an answer.

Comment: See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952428/programmatically-get-current-ipython-notebook-cell-output

Answer (score 17):

[See this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994137/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-cell-in-ipython-notebook)

You can use %%capture Jupyter notebook' magic command to catch output of cell and then paste it to your text file with

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
   out.write(cap.stdout)
```

if you want to cell code to specific file for example code.txt you can use magic function %%writefile

```
%%writefile example.txt
ab = 'This is code'
a = 5
print(a+ 2)
```

Also if you want to append to file you must use -a parameter

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. What I want to export is not the result of a cell but the code I wrote into that cell.

Comment: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html Then you can use %%writefile magic function

Comment: In that case, we cannot execute code. Could we execute the code and at the same time write the code into a file?

Comment: It is super helpful for me :)

Answer (score 4):

You can register a new cell magic, for example:

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
@register_cell_magic
def run_and_save(line, cell):
    'Run and save python code block to a file'
    with open(line, 'wt') as fd:
        fd.write(cell)
    code = compile(cell, line, 'exec')
    exec(code, globals())
```

Now, you can use the run_and_save magic:

```
%%run_and_save hello.py

class Hello:
   def __init__(self):
      pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is possible to export only one cell in *Jupyter* notebooks.

But I do know that you could download as a python file and simply copy paste the particular cell you want in your new *Jupyter* notebook.

Let me know if you need any more help!

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be done is to use Python's [output caching system](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system) to access the output of a cell so it can be saved off to a file. The output from a numbered cell x is stored in a variable named `_x`, and output from the last command is in `_` etc. e.g. Save the output of cell number 10 to a file `cell_10.pickle` using python's pickle format:

```
import pickle
with open('cell_10.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(_10, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```